# Why is my Mongo DB not catching more than 1 of my links?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, axios

Update on issue.  I now have everything in my mongo db but nothing is showing up on my page. Appears to be something to do with bootbox.  If I click scrape new articles previous dialog disappears and scrape happens successfully.  Upon inspect a new bootbox section appears with an empty h3 tag.

https://github.com/TylerCEdge/tester

Currently I get all 20 of the results console logged and all are going to mongo but nothing is showing up on my page.  It's probably a spelling error but I'm having trouble with it.

```
// Scrape Script
// =============

// Require axios and cheerio
var axios = require("axios");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");


var URL = "https://thehackernews.com/search?"


function scrape(cb) {
    // First, we grab the body of the html with axios
    axios.get(URL).then(function (response) {
        // Then, we load that into cheerio and save it to $ for a shorthand selector
        var $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
        var articles = [];

        // Now, we grab every h2 within an article tag, and do the following:
        $("h2").each(function () {
            // Save an empty dataToAdd object
            var dataToAdd = {};

            // Add the text and href of every link, and save them as properties of the dataToAdd object
            dataToAdd.title = $(this)
                .text()
                // Removes unwanted characters from the titles
                .replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, ' ');
            dataToAdd.link = $(this)
                .parent().parent().parent().parent()
                .find("a")
                .attr("href");
            dataToAdd.img = $(this)
                .parent().parent().parent()
                .find("div.home-img").find("div.img-ratio").find("img")
                .attr("data-src")
            dataToAdd.summary = $(this)
                .parent()
                .find("div.home-desc")
                .text()
                .replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, ' ')


            // console.log(dataToAdd);
            articles.push(dataToAdd);
            // for (i = 0; i = dataToAdd.length; i++) {
            //     articles.push(dataToAdd[i]);
            // }
        });
        cb(articles);
        console.log(articles);
    });
};

module.exports = scrape;

// Server routes

// Import Scrape
var scrape = require("../scripts/scrape");

// Import headlines/notes
var headlinesController = require("../controllers/headlines");
var notesController = require("../controllers/notes");

module.exports = function (router) {
    router.get("/", function (req, res) {
        res.render("home");
    });
    router.get("/saved", function (req, res) {
        res.render("saved");
    });

    router.get("/api/fetch", function (req, res) {
        headlinesController.fetch(function (err, docs) {
            if (!docs || docs.insertedCount === 0) {
                res.json({
                    message: "no new articles today. Check back tomorrow!"
                });
            }
            else {
                res.json({
                    message: "Added " + docs.insertedCount + " new articles!"
                });
            }
        });
    });
    router.get("/api/headlines", function (req, res) {
        var query = {};
        if (req.query.saved) {
            query = req.query;
        }
        headlinesController.get(query, function (data) {
            res.json(data);
        });
    });
    router.delete("/api/headlines/:id", function (req, res) {
        var query = {};
        query._id = req.params.id;
        headlinesController.delete(query, function (err, data) {
            res.json(data);
        });
    });
    router.get("/api/notes/:headline_id?", function (req, res) {
        var query = {};
        if (req.params.headline_id) {
            query._id = req.params.headline_id;
        }
        notesController.get(query, function (err, data) {
            res.json(data);
        });
    });
    router.delete("/api/notes/:id", function (req, res) {
        var query = {};
        query._id = req.params.id;
        notesController.delete(query, function (err, data) {
            res.json(data);
        });
    });
    router.post("/api/notes", function (req, res) {
        notesController.save(req.body, function (data) {
            res.json(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Your question currently resembles a [Big Ball Of Mud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud). You need to reduce your question down to one specific issue.

Comment: @BlueWater86 I did my best to rectify the issue.  I now have my data posting to /api/headlines and its showing in my mongo db but nothing is posting to the page.  Just a blank section where its supposed to go.  It looks like everything is wired up correctly so I'm confused as to why its not rendering.

Comment: You're nearly there but I still can't provide an answer without going off-site to your github repo.

Comment: You have code that is importing and using your `scrape` module right? Where is this code in your question.

Comment: @BlueWater86 added routes.js to the code.

Comment: In the edit provided you still have not called scrape.

Comment: Also, what is it that you are inspecting?

Comment: inspecting the home page before clicking scrape articles theres no bootbox section after clicking there is.  Also a section that doesnt render to the page that says it scraped 20 new articles but nothing actually renders.

Comment: https://postimg.cc/9r0PXBMV